# Detect if R Script is Running in Interpreter or from Command Line

Tags: r, command-line, interpreter

Certain functions in R appear to behave slightly differently depending on whether a script is run in an interpreter or called from the command line.  For instance, if I print certain types of plot objects from within the interpreter, they simply display on my screen, with no new files created.  If I run the same script from the command line using `Rscript ...`, however, R will automatically save a .pdf of the plot, under the name `Rplots.pdf` in whatever my current working directory is.  I find this unwanted creation of files undesirable.

Ideally, I'd like a way to encapsulate my `print()` commands in some kind of logical test that would check if the script is running from an interpreter.  Alternatively, if there is some different way to use the `print()` function, or some alternative to it, that could avoid the creation of unwanted files, that would also be a satisfactory result.

See below for minimal working script:

```
# Rscript "Interpreter_Question.R"

library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=rnorm(10))
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_point()

print(p1)
```

Comment: `?interactive`....?

Comment: `if (interactive()) cat("I am interactive\n")`